# How can I validate a MongoDB document using a validation schema from a file?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to validate document before it is inserted into the database. I know that I can set static validator, but I would prefer to have a file with the validation schemas that I could modify at any time.

```
//example schema
const userCreateValidationSchema = {
        bsonType: 'object',
        required: ['username', 'password'],
        properties: {
            username: {
                bsonType: 'string',
                maxLength: 16,
            },
            password: {
                bsonType: 'string',
                maxLength: 64,
            },
        },
        additionalProperties: false,
};

//example document
const document = {
        username: "user",
        password: "passwd",
};
```

Then I would do something like `validate(document, userCreateValidationSchema)`.

Thanks for any thoughts.

I have tried looking for the answer in the documentation but unfortunatelly didn't find the solution.